# Getting total word frequencies for a subset of documents in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I'm needing to get the frequency of a term and the value of the term in relation to the subset of documents

For example, the Search returns the frequency in relation to all documents.

`IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);`

```
int docFreq = searcher.docFreq(new Term("name", "museu"));
```

or TermDocs can do the same thing

```
TermDocs termDocs = reader.termDocs(new Term("name", "museu"));
termDocs.freq();
```

how to do this for a document or subset of documents?